# How to use Cakedc users plugin for login and also with social accounts

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.0, cakedc

I have installed users plugin with all other 5 plugins for different social login. When i login normally, it gives me a redirect URL error and when i click to the login with Facebook, it takes me to myproject/auth/Facebook. I don't know what i have to create for this Url just need little guidance. Thank you in Advance

App Controller

```
class AppController extends Controller
{


    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
//        $this->loadComponent('Security');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('CakeDC/Users.UsersAuth');

}   

    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }
    }

}
```

I have Added this Code in Bootstrap.php

```
Configure::write('Users.Social.login', true); //to enable social login

Configure::write('OAuth.providers.facebook.options.clientId', '8660982830167491');
Configure::write('OAuth.providers.facebook.options.clientSecret', 'secret');

Configure::write('OAuth.providers.google.options.clientId', '7724091450376-birdmh5a3t48b8mg9knq0lonup6aeomk.apps.googleusercontent.com');
Configure::write('OAuth.providers.google.options.clientSecret', 'secret');


Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users', ['routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true]);

Configure::write('OAuth.providers.facebook.options.clientId', '17076687932896982');
Configure::write('OAuth.providers.facebook.options.clientSecret', 'be3ca9743ae0bd278ee61c4bda770907fc');

Configure::write('OAuth.providers.twitter.options.clientId', '1082264240790-8ns1ohig1f3iqlgo9okac3kr3p50j44det.apps.googleusercontent.com');
Configure::write('OAuth.providers.twitter.options.clientSecret', 'odSeNKMK5dWpQpfNu8LbGX_K');
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation [link](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/SocialAuthenticate.md) ?

Comment: have you found the solution for this ? I am facing similar issue, i am able to do social login but normal login gives error message username or password is incorrent when social login is enabled, otherwise it works fine.